# I have a Dual Channel Motherboard - Should I use 4x4GB or 2x8GB Memory?

Tags: memory

I have an MSI FXA990-GD80 motherboard. I'm looking at getting 16GB for it. I am not interested in upgrading in the future so no need to keep spare slots.

The motherboard is dual channel, supports upto DDR3 2133MHz memory.

I am looking at getting this memory, but not sure whether 2X8GB or 4X4GB would be the best option in terms of Performance:

Hyper X Beast Series 16GB 2133MHz DDR3 Non-ECC CL11 DIMM (Kit of 2) XMP

Comment: What's the primary purpose of this machine? If it's a gaming/general-use machine, you [i]really[/i] don't need to worry about memory. Check the manual for your motherboard on how to set up dual channel, buy the amount of memory you need, install the modules, and be done with it.

Comment: Buy whatever is cheapest.

Comment: @Ramhound - Why?

Comment: @happy_soil so you're saying that 2X8GB sticks is exactly the same as 4x4GB sticks?

Comment: @user2924019 Because both will work?

Comment: @Ramhound Well you didn't read the question in that case and obviously don't understand memory.

Comment: @user2924019 - You are absolutely correct, I don't understand memory in the slightest, despite having numerous answers to questions like this under my belt.  There will be absolutely zero measureable performance gains from using two sticks instead four sticks.  I was trying to help you save a few bucks.  If you don't believe me feel free to benchmark it yourself.

Comment: Why not answer that, rather than "Buy whatever is cheapest". I asked what was best in terms of performance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be *little to no benefit* in terms of performance between the two.

Memory, for a long time, hasn't played a huge role on improving performance, i.e. "more" FPS in gaming.

That particular memory you're looking at is relatively expensive. You don't need fast memory. You're better off saving your money for better CPU, GPU, or storage (e.g. SSD), because that's where you'll see the performance gains you're after (better frame rates, graphics, and load times, respectively).

Comment: Thanks, someone who actually read the question. Can you believe others said to use either as they both will work?!